# Uploading mp4 file to the database by using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, smarty, mp4

I'm working on implementing the web site that consits of php, mysql, smarty, and am facing an issue of not being able to upload a mp4 file to the database at the registration screen which I am able to upload with jpg file.

When I click the upload button there it shows the % of uploading progressin at the lower left hand coner of the screen upto around 99% and then it says at the end "file format is unknown" that's from the php coding below on the client with white screen on the back, and it doesn't say any error message at the server.

My question is if you can tell from the coding below something wrong with case "1" which is for mp4, and case "2" is for jpg which is working fine. Or is it that some other coding that are related to the uploading function might be causing this problem? Or is it those kind of issue that it would be solved if I could install ffmpeg on the appache server?  I'd appreciate if you could help me out.

Code:

```
function Main($path, $width, $height, $dst_file, $header = false) {

    if(!isset($path)) {
        return array(0, "Image path is not set.");
    }

    if(!file_exists($path)) {
        return array(0, "The file can not be found in the specified path.");
    }

    // Set the size of the image
    if($width) $this->imgMaxWidth = $width;
    if($height) $this->imgMaxHeight = $height;

    $size = @GetimageSize($path);
    $re_size = $size;

    //Aspect ratio fixed processing
    if($this->imgMaxWidth != 0) {
        $tmp_w = $size[0] / $this->imgMaxWidth;
    }

    if($this->imgMaxHeight != 0) {
        $tmp_h = $size[1] / $this->imgMaxHeight;
    }

    if($tmp_w > 1 || $tmp_h > 1) {
        if($this->imgMaxHeight == 0) {
            if($tmp_w > 1) {
                $re_size[0] = $this->imgMaxWidth;
                $re_size[1] = $size[1] * $this->imgMaxWidth / $size[0];
            }
        } else {
            if($tmp_w > $tmp_h) {
                $re_size[0] = $this->imgMaxWidth;
                $re_size[1] = $size[1] * $this->imgMaxWidth / $size[0];
            } else {
                $re_size[1] = $this->imgMaxHeight;
                $re_size[0] = $size[0] * $this->imgMaxHeight / $size[1];
            }
        }
    }

    $imagecreate = function_exists("imagecreatetruecolor") ? "imagecreatetruecolor" : "imagecreate";
    $imageresize = function_exists("imagecopyresampled") ? "imagecopyresampled" : "imagecopyresized";

    switch($size[2]) {
    case "1":

        if ($header) {
            header("Content-Type: video/mp4");

            $dst_im = copy($path, $dst_file);
            return "";
        } else {
            $dst_file = $dst_file . ".mp4";

            $dst_im = copy($path, $dst_file);
        }
        unlink($dst_im);

        break;

    case "2":

        $src_im = imageCreateFromJpeg($path);
        $dst_im = $imagecreate($re_size[0], $re_size[1]);

        $imageresize($dst_im, $src_im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $re_size[0], $re_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

        if ($header) {
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            imageJpeg($dst_im);
            return "";
        } else {
            $dst_file = $dst_file . ".jpg";
            if ($re_size[0] == $size[0] && $re_size[1] == $size[1]) {
                copy($path, $dst_file);
            } else {
                imageJpeg($dst_im, $dst_file);
            }
        }

        imagedestroy($src_im);
        imagedestroy($dst_im);

        break;

    default:
        return array(
            0,
            "file format is unknown"
        );
}
return array(
    1,
    $dst_file
);
```

Comment: That error message appears when the switch does not enter case "1" or "2". So, how do you decide that an MP4 file needs to end up in case "1"? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Thanks, rickdenhaan. The description of the entire cordings were written in foreign languages so I need some time to edit it. I wonder why case "2" is working then. So do you think that mp4 can be uploaded as long as the cording was fixed?

Comment: The reason you see "file format is unknown" is not because of a problem with this code, but with the code before it. Somewhere you have `switch ($some_variable) {`, and for MP4 files you expect that `$some_variable` is "1". The problem is where you define `$some_variable`. Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: Thanks,rickdenhaan. I've just added the code. So, is mp4 bypassing @GetimageSize since it only look for image file? What would you do in the situation like this?

Comment: Yes, `getimagesize()` only works on images, not on videos. If you remove the `@` you should see a notice about that. I would personally use [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/mime_content_type) from the Fileinfo extension to determine what type of file I'm dealing with. But the first thing I would do is remove any `@` characters and enable error reporting so I can see when something's not working.

Comment: Thanks,rickdenhaan. I've not received any error on the server after I deleted @ from the code. If it's possible, could you show me how to use mime_content_type() on the code above instead of getimagesize() so that I can achieve what I want which is, in this case, to upload mp4 to the server, or at least move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getimagesize()` only works on images. Its behavior on video files is undefined, it *may* give a width and height but it will probably just fail. Even if it *does* work, `$size[2]` will not be "1" because that would mean it's a GIF image.

I would use `mime_content_type()` to determine what type of file was uploaded. This will return a mimetype for the uploaded file, which means that you need to have multiple cases to deal with image files:

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type($path);

switch ($mimetype) {
    case "video/mp4":
        // what is currently your case "1"
        break;

    case "image/jpeg":
    case "image/pjpeg":
    case "image/png":
    case "image/gif":
        // what is currently your case "2"
        break;

    default:
        return array(
            0,
            "file format is unknown"
        );
}
```

This function is part of the [Fileinfo](https://php.net/fileinfo) extension, which you may need to install if it's not already enabled on your server.

Comment: Thanks, rickdenhaan.  Now I have a similar question which I was gonna post new one. When I click the upload button at the registration screen it'll upload mp4 to the db, but it'll not show anything at the screen (I deleated the autoplay from html) unless I click the start button from control bar. What kind of setting do I need, or how can I show the image (the very first image) of the video file at the screen when I finished uploading the mp4 to the db. Or, at the list page or the front page, not the detail page,  how will the video images be shown without running?

Comment: @user27240 Yeah, that should be a new question (or two), since playback is primarily a HTML/Javascript issue, whereas retrieving the first frame from a video is unrelated to storing something in the database.

Comment: rickdenhaan, Now I can upload mp4 and mov to the database by your script, even though I have not tested files like avi, wmv, and others yet. Anyway, thanks a lot for your support.